# Getting text in "textbox" instead of alert

Tags: jquery, html

Ok so I got this jquery code to show facebook likes:

```
<script>
  $.getJSON("https://graph.facebook.com/TuamadreLeggenda?callback=?", function(data) { 
  alert("Likes: " + data.likes); 
});
</script>
```

How can I show the data in the alert in a p tag or a font tag for example instead of getting an annoying alert?

Answer (score 1):

The following code will put your `data.likes` in all `<p>` tags on your page.

```
<script>
  $.getJSON("https://graph.facebook.com/TuamadreLeggenda?callback=?", function(data) { 
  $("p").html(data.likes); 
});
</script>
```

If you prefer to target a specific tag you will need the id of the HTML element and use it like so:

```
$("#YourIdHere").html(data.likes);
```

Comment: It seems like there is no id that refers specifically to the likes number but the first solution is fine. Thanks :) If you can find it in https://graph.facebook.com/TuamadreLeggenda?callback=? I'd be thankful though.

Comment: The ID is not something I would be able to find in the data that is returned by that link. This data could be used by any page on the internet. I would need to know specifically the page you are making the call from to tell you how to put it on that page.

Answer (score 0):

Just change your alert to something like:

```
$('p').html(data.likes);
```

Where `$('p')` is the selector for the element you want to show it in.